# How to Back-up and Restore a Datastore between applications

Tags: backup, google-cloud-storage, restore, google-cloud-datastore

I have one full datastore on an app and I need to transfer it to its predecessor app.

Here I found documentation that is completely incorrect:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin

My first issue is that it references a a Data menu option on the left side, which does not exist. It also mentions a datastore admin portion which does not exist either.

What is the easiest way to get the datastore from one application to another?
I wouldnt mind copying files locally and uploading them to the other, or something indirect.

Also why is their documentation so off? Have parts been deprecated?

EDIT---------------------------------------------------------------

okay so it has been pointed out to me that I was using the new console, which can not do this specific request.

Now, when reading through the documentation, it tells me I need to find the bucketname for the backups I made, or the file Handle name.

For the bucketname ive tried id.appspot.com in which it gives me an error that it is "not accessable".
I have added the account im using to the permissions of the other account already.

As for the Handle, the documentation says there is a button to show what it is, but once again it is just completely wrong

Any help would be great

Comment: at the top of the page you link to, it says "this only works on appengine.google.com". I guess you went to "console.developers.google.com"?

Answer (score 2):

For now, Backup and restore Datastore only works in [Admin Console](https://appengine.google.com) ([https://appengine.google.com/](https://appengine.google.com)). You need to select your project after going to admin console. Then Datastore menu should appear on the left side/column.

Comment: Thank you, that did bring me to where I needed to be, but unfortunately, now I have to find the bucket-name of my backups, which i thought was <App ID>.appspot.com, but that one is not working